# Animate Javascript classList.toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I recently started to learn CSS and HTML and found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp) tutorial for a responsive navbar.

They show the mobile version of the navbar with the javascript function classList.toggle. Is there any way to animate this and add a transition?

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");}
```

Comment: It is better for you to provide what effort you made to achieve what you want.. check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/) and also try reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and more about the site.. And since you take guidance from w3schools check [this for transition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transition.asp)... welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the class attribute, but you can animate CSS properties.

You should have an initial CSS definition for your `.topnav` class, like this one:

```
.topnav {
    background-color: black; /* Set an initial background */
    transition: background-color 200ms; /* Tell browser to use a transition when background-color changed */
}
```

Thanks to this code, anytime the background-color of your `.topnav` element will change, a transition will occur.

You can for example add this CSS:

```
.topnav.responsive {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And this will work with your JS code.

Of course, my examples are basic and will just add a transition for the background-color, but it should help you about your problem :)